# Responsive header with text and button

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am making a simple header with text and a button but when I go on mobile everything isn't responsive . I tried using %'s but nothing was working. And my CSS jumps up and down when I scroll on mobile. This is the codepen, https://codepen.io/Religion/pen/ZEQerQZ. Below is the CSS . HTML you can check on the codepen due to the post saying it's mostly code.
CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.header1{
  padding: 15%;
  text-align: center;

  background-image: url('https://manchesterdental.org/img/dentalimg/welcomenote.jpg');
   background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: relative;

}
.header-text1 h2{
  margin-top:20%;
  font-size:1.8rem;
  width:45vh; 
  margin-left:-20%;
  color:white;



 
}
.header-text1 p{
 
    font-size:1.1rem;
  width:44vh; 
  margin-left:-20%;
  padding-top:40px;
  color:white;
  font-weight: 500;



}
.header-text{
   position: absolute;
   bottom:0;
   left:0;

   
   
   width:1px;



}
.button {
  background-color: #00aeef; /* Green */
  
  color: black;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  margin-left: 2%;
  width:95%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  
}
}

@media (min-width:900px) {
  .header1{
  padding: 60px;
  text-align: center;

  background-image: url("{% static 'dentist/img/bg-img/header.jpg' %}");
   background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  height:80vh;
 
}
.header-text1 h2{
  margin-top:10%;
  color:white;
font-size: 3rem;


 
}
.header-text1 p{
 padding-top:40px;
 font-size:1.5rem;
 max-width:80%;
 margin-left:10%;
 
 
  color:white;
  font-weight: 500;



}
.button {
  background-color: #00aeef; /* Green */
  
  color: black;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  margin-left: 2%;
  width:45%;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
  font-weight:800;

  
}
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="header1">
  <div class = "header-text1">
  <h2>We Believe Everyone Should Have Easy Access To Great Dental Care</h2>
  <p >As a leading industry innovater, * Dental Business* is opening up exciting new opportunities for dental professionals, investors, employees & suppliers. Contact us to find out what we have to offer you.</p>
  <br>
 <a href="{% url 'contact' %}"><button class="button button1">Contact Us!</button></a>

  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add your html file as well so I can try and reproduce your code?

Comment: Just added it^^

Comment: Ok I've looked it over a bit, but I'm confused on what effect you want exactly. You say that the css "jumps up and down", so do you want the text to remain at the same height regardless of viewport size? Or something else...

Comment: I don't want any effect I just want my text and everything centered on mobile staying still. Because another problem i was having was my css kept jumping around when I scrolled on mobile

Comment: I posted the screen shot of how I want it to look. On iphone x it apparently looks fine but on every other device it  isnt responsive

Comment: How about [this?](https://codepen.io/itsanewabstract/pen/jOWBZad?editors=1100) Does this look right?

Comment: yes perfect thank you so much it had me stuck for a while

Comment: No problem! I'll post it as an answer and add an explanation too. Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the text elements centered in the div, you can make use of `flexbox`. Simply add the following code to the top of your CSS file before the media queries:

```
.header-text1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
 
  width: 100%;
```

}

Also, no need to include this with your media queries since `flexbox` will handle everything regardless of viewport size.

This [Codepen](https://codepen.io/itsanewabstract/pen/jOWBZad?editors=1100) had the updated code - also changed the second media query so that the CSS doesn't break between 767px and 900px like it did before.

Answer (score 1):

You are currently setting the `margin-top` property to 20% of the height of the button itself.

If you want the margin to respond to the width of the viewport, then use something like:

```
margin-top: 2vw; // 2% of the viewport width
```

However, for the `margin-top` property, I suggest using the height of the viewport like so:

```
margin-top: 1vh; // 1% of the viewport height (1% should be enough)
```